# How to Ignore a JsonProperty to be stored in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my POJO that I use to store in DynamoDB using DynamodbMapper

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Data")
// @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "content" })
public class Data {
    @DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName = "Url")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    @JsonProperty("url")
    private String url;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "UserName")
    @JsonProperty("userName")
    private String userName;

    @JsonProperty("title")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Title")
    private String pasteTitle;

    @JsonProperty("content")
    private String content;

    @JsonProperty("date")
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Date")
    private String date;

}
```

Every time I run `DynamoDBMapper.save(data)`, it stores `content` as well even if it does not have `DynamoDBAttribute` annotation. By using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "content" })` it makes the value as null and does not store the content. But I would like to store the content in S3 and not DynamoDB and hence looking for a way to ignore this in DynamoDBAttribute.

Comment: Did you tried @jsonignore over property named content?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as you can see I have commented it on line 2. If I ignore it, it returns null value even if I pass the value for `content` in the json object.

Comment: For now, I solved the problem by setting the `content` to null after storing it in S3, so that it does not get stored in DynamoDB(since DynamoDB is very expensive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@DynamoDBIgnore` - [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.html#DynamoDBMapper.Annotations.DynamoDBIgnore)

In your example:

```
    @DynamoDBIgnore
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it's @DynamoDbIgnore annotation.. not @DynamoDBIgnore

Comment: That's not what the documentation says.

Comment: This is what I am using in projects with 
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb-enhanced:2.19.0'